# Configuring thread name prefix in Jetty transport

Tags: spring, jetty, cxf

It would be great if someone was able to help me with the following.

We currently use Jetty to expose our REST interface (Which is setup with Spring) and I want to be able to set the prefix of the threads that are used to process these calls. I believe I have found the change to cxf that will enable this behaviour:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5919

It seems to change the initial "qtp" value to whatever you want. (The version we have does include these changes) The problem is that I cannot actually work out how to set it, initially I tried the following:

```
<Configure id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Set name="threadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads">1000</Set>
      <Set name="threadNamePrefix">myname</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/jetty.xml_syntax#Creating_a_NewObject_and_Setting_It_on_the_Server

But that does not work as it's not the QueuedThreadPool that has the threadNamePrefix value.

I would be great if someone was able to give me some pointers as to how I can update my jetty.xml so that I can set this value.

Thank you

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Jetty source code I see that `name` attribute is the one you are after. Your example should look like this:

```
<Configure id="server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Set name="threadPool">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
      <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
      <Set name="maxThreads">1000</Set>
      <Set name="name">myname</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

This is the result (from VisualVM) on my setup: 
[image: Thread names as seen in VisualVM]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer and give a detailed breakdown, but I think that updates all the thread names doesn't it? - The change I'm after is just the "HTTP Jetty transport" ones (as detailed in CXF-5919) - Thanks, Rob

Comment: You can define a different thread pool for every Jetty connector. What CXF transport do you use? Jetty of Servlet? I would think you configure jetty `engine` (and possibly `connector` as well) somewhere in Spring config. You can redefine the connector you want to use there. Could you update the question with some sample config?